# Need to provide a way to connect to multiple SOAP Endpoints programmatically

Tags: c#, soap, endpoints

**Given:**
Multiple clients with a `Service.asmx` page that has some web methods that I need to connect to.

A Utility function that takes input to determine which client needs to be connected to. This is what I have so far:

```
public static MyServiceSoapClient SoapClientFactory(string clientCode)
{
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message, false);
    var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(
        new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}.mydomain.com/Service.asmx", clientCode)),
        new UpnEndpointIdentity("myservice@domain.com"));

    return new MyServiceSoapClient(binding, remoteAddress);
}
```

This method completes with no errors (note: I don't know what the EndPointIdentity is so I just came up with a string to put in there... not sure if this should be in a config setting somewhere else or what?)

**Problem:**
While trying to make the call to the remote method, an exception is thrown and its not very descriptive (A `NullReferenceException`). Here's the code:

```
// point to the correct Service.asmx url.
var client = Util.SoapClientFactory(clientCode);

// now make the soap call.
var result = client.GetSomeStuff(someParameter); // throws the exception.
```

The stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Server stack trace:
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenTokenProviderIfRequired(SecurityTokenProvider tokenProvider, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    at ... my function call. (i.e. client.GetSomeStuff(someParameter) )
```

Comment: Is this the entire result of `ex.ToString()`? There is no `InnerException`? Also, does this happen for all clients?

Comment: @John Saunders this is the entire result of `ex.ToString()`. Also, `ex.InnerExcetion` was `null`.

Comment: What happens if you simplify the code in the factory? What if you use a static, known-good URL? What if you use a configured binding via the configuration name instead of creating one? This would help narrow down where the issue might be. Of course, this is clearly a bug in WCF - whatever object it's failing to dereference, it should have checked it first and you should have received an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: John, I figured it out for now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. What I do is I create a Soap client using the default constructor (this always works but then im stuck with the Uri that I've configured during development) What I do then is set the `Endpoint`'s `Address` property it worked like a charm!

```
var client = new MySoapClient();

// this can also be set using Web.config parameter now or a value stored in a database etc.
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:3000/Service.asmx");
return client;
```